# Por que o "print" do Lua imprime espaços extras nos argumentos?

Tags: lua, print

Utilizei o comando `print()` concatenando uma variável, mas a saída imprime espaços extras. Se eu usar o `io.write()`, esse problema não ocorre. Por que esse problema acontece com o `print()`?

Exemplo:

```lua
name = "Peter"

print("The length of the name is: ", #name)
```

Resultado esperado: `The length of the name is: 5`

Resultado obtido: `The length of the name is:  5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função print em lua adiciona um `tab` entre cada argumento, o código que descreve isto está disponivel no github:

https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/681297187ec45268e872b26753c441586c12bdd8/lbaselib.c#L31

Para ganhar mais controle no output, use o `io.write`

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui entender. Pelo que eu entendi o print() é pra usar pra imprimir sem formatação, se tiver esses casos é pra usar o io.write()

Answer (score 3):

Verificando a documentação da função [`print()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-print):

> Recebe um número qualquer de argumentos e imprime seus valores em
> `stdout`, usando a função [`tostring()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tostring) para converter cada
> argumento passado em uma `string`. `print()` não se destina a saída
> formatada mas apenas como uma maneira rápida de mostrar um valor, por
> exemplo para depuração. Para controle completo sobre a saída, use
> [`string.format()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format) e [`io.write()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-io.write).

Exemplo usando `io.write()`:

```
nome = "Augusto Vasques"      
io.write("O comprimento da string é: ",#nome)    --O comprimento da string é: 15
```

Answer (score -4):

use a concatenação com dois pontos (..)

print( "Teste:"..123)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).